# MySQL perfomance issues in SELECT

Tags: mysql, performance

A simple database:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  code VARCHAR(50),
  value VARCHAR(10),
);
```

There are currently ~2 millions rows.

Query like:

```
SELECT value FROM data WHERE `code`='12345';
```

executes for 10-12 seconds.

What the best way to increase performance of simple `select` queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an index on the `code` column:

```
ALTER TABLE data ADD INDEX (code)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add index to code. Also, is code always numeric (make it type int) and/or is it unique (make it unique or primary key)?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you may find that adding an index on the `code` column does not suffice, so if that doesn't work for you you would need to add a (single) index for both the `code` and `value` columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to ask MySQL for information about how it's going to execute your query.  This would tell you that it needs to check every row.  Improving this is a matter of adding an index on the `code` column which is used in your `WHERE` clause.

`EXPLAIN`
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html

`CREATE INDEX`
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html